# wfastcgi.py on IIS 10 closing because of empty data on cgi record

Tags: python, iis, fastcgi, iis-10, wfastcgi

I'm trying to migrate a python backend application from IIS 8.5 to IIS 10 in a new server. While in the old server the application works just fine, in the new one it is getting a 500 error.

I tried to debug the issue and it seems that wfastcgi exit because at some point during the handling of a PUT request it finds the CGI record empty, the application closes and then another request times out because of this. IIS documentation says that there are no changes in the FastCGI behavior between 8.5 and 10 but that seems to be incorrect. Does anyone know which are the differences in behavior or why this could be happening only on a IIS 10 environemnt?

In summary this is what is happening:

- A PUT request is sent to the server. It shows a 200 status, so no error
- The wfascgi logs though show the following:

2023-08-08 09:28:05.406145: Running on_exit tasks

2023-08-08 09:28:05.406145: wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 closed

- GET request comes through and times out apparently because wfastcgi is down. failed request debug shows a times out from the FastCGI module.

Exactly the same process works just fine in the old server. wfastcgi does not close after the PUT request and GET request is processed just fine. This has been tested using failed request tracing and enabling wfastcgi logs in the old server too.

Only difference between the servers is OS Version/IIS version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error.

Comment: Failed request tracing only shows a time out for the 500 error. I added more debugging notes to the description.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, can you post the contents of the failed request trace log?